# Как сделать переиспользуемые кнопки в react?

Tags: reactjs

У кнопок будут к примеру 3 размера:
маленькая, средняя, большая
и например 3 цвета

Как лучше реализовать такой компонент и чтобы удобно было использовать?

Comment: Выведите в пропсы эти данные (внутри самого компонента) и при его подключении из вне указывайте нужное Вам.

Comment: Для подобных случаев есть "значения по умолчанию":
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №1 (простое условие):

```
import React from "react";

export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { size, variant, text, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={`btn-size-${size || "medium"} btn-variant-${variant || "default"}`}
      >
        <span className="btn-text">{text || children}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Вариант №2 ([*PropTypes*](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)):

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { size, variant, text, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={`btn-size-${size} btn-variant-${variant}`}
      >
        <span className="btn-text">{text || children}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  size: "medium",
  variant: "default",
};

Button.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(["small", "medium", "large"]),
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(["primary", "secondary", "disabled", "default"]),
  text: PropTypes.string
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: Еще `text` можно заменить на props.children, чтобы можно было рендерить `<Button ...>Все что угодно</Button>`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov согласен

Comment: Вариант №2. как в таком случае тогда использовать button large? у нас ведь по дефолту medium. Просто при рендере в props писать?

Comment: Ну да, а вы как хотели?)

Comment: примерно так и представлял) текст тоже в props писать?

Comment: Да, или заключать внутрь тега `<Button>Send</Button>`

Answer (score -1):

Можно еще создать готовые кнопки с классами, стилями и тд, а потом просто их вызывать:

кнопки

```
export const DarkButton = props => <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-dark" {...props}/>;
export const DangerButton = props => <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-danger" {...props}/>;
```

вызов:

```
render(<div>
    <DarkButton>dark button</DarkButton>
    <DangerButton>danger button</DangerButton>
</div>)
```

свойства кнопки можно переопределять:

```
<DarkButton className="...">dark button</DarkButton>
```

Comment: да ну... при вариантах трех цветов и трех размеров получается 9 кнопок, зачем?